# really old "xstrings.h" - feature modernized for embedded work

Tags: c++, c, gcc, embedded, c-strings

A long time ago, I remember a unix tool that would scan your C source code and modify all constant strings it found with a macro.

I seem to remember this was called: xstrings.h or string extract, but it was 30 years ago.. Back then RAM at the time was expensive, today it is cheap (on a linux platform)
I think this was also used back then for internationalization.. Its been +30 years!

This would read/modify your source code and create a strings data file. At run time the macro would call some function that would load the strings from a file. The macro called some function passing a string number which was used to fetch the string from the file.

Today - gcc places these in the TEXT segment that effectively "bloats" the code.

what I am getting at is this:

How can I remove/replace/reduce ascii text debug strings in my embedded code I compile with GCC - because the DAMN strings are bloating my code beyond all fatness.

The problem is in embedded code - FLASH space is at an utmost premium much like RAM was back in the day that XSTRINGS existed.

One technique that I have seen is this:  You have 2 classes of strings Class(A) must be present in the ROM IMAGE, and Class(B) debug stuff you can remove or discard from the ROM.

The trick is you would use the macro to place all "discard able" strings into a separate ELF SECTION, in the linker you mark the section as NO_LOAD. This makes them sort of like a BSS VARIABLE - it has an address but does not take up space in the FLASH.

And you don't want to get rid of the "printf()" arg checking for other reasons - the macro can do multiple things as needed.

yea, printf() type log functions are challenge here but debug log functions can be created to solve the those issues in very simple ways.

To get rid of the strings the DEBUG code that performs logging instead logs the "address" of the string to the log stream not the text. Thus what is logged is often a 32bit integer/string identifier.

Since in the chip address space every address is a unique number, you have plenty (4gig - no embedded platform is that big!) The LOG PARSER (external to the app) would read the 32bit string address and fetch it from the ELF file to reconstruct the string.

The advantage the XSTRINGS() had is stable string numbers across builds. I'd be more then  happy to give that up.. to KEEP my debug strings and remove the DEBUG bloat!

There are other things that could be done too but this is the simple one.

Comment: Are you thinking of [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)? A program called [`xgettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) is part of that package.